# Reference subquery field for greater than clause in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a query that I can do with raw sql but am trying to convert it to use the Django ORM. The query is:

```
 SELECT a.journey_pattern_ref_id
 FROM(
     SELECT * FROM journeypatterntiminglink
     WHERE from_stop_id = '0180BAC30249'
 ) a,
 journeypatterntiminglink b
 WHERE a.journey_pattern_ref_id = b.journey_pattern_ref_id
 AND b.to_stop_id = '0180BAC30035'
 AND b.to_seq_no > a.from_seq_no;
```

The part that is giving me trouble is `b.to_seq_no > a.from_seq_no`. So far I have

```
jps = (JourneyPattern.objects                                                                                                       
           .filter(journeypatterntiminglink__from_stop=origin)
           .filter(journeypatterntiminglink__to_stop=destination))
```

Comment: Didn't my answer worked?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should use [*F() expressions*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions) to reference other fields in query construction rather than constants.

Inferring the definition of your model from your question it should be something like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

jps = (JourneyPattern.objects
       .filter(journeypatterntiminglink__from_stop=origin)
       .filter(journeypatterntiminglink__to_stop=destination)
       .filter(journeypatterntiminglink__to_seq_no__gt=F('journeypatterntiminglink__from_seq_no'))
```